# Combine tags [msf4j] and [wso2msf4j]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

The [msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msf4j) (42 questions) and [wso2msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2msf4j) (17 questions, with 15 also having [mso4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mso4j)) tags refer to the same product (WSO2 Microservices Framework for Java).

[wso2msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2msf4j) should either be eliminated (replacing it with the [wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2) and [msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msf4j) tags), or made a synonym of [msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msf4j). Both wiki entries for [wso2msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2msf4j) are more detailed and should be copied over to replace the existing [msf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msf4j) entries.

I'm not sure which would be the better solution, as I am not familiar with the product.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Relevant to anyone active in the WSO2 tags: [Proposed updates to WSO2 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418604/1478931)